# Bengali characters messed up in ubuntu terminal

Tags: internationalization, input-method

I am running ubuntu 16.04.

I can type in bengali in gedit on my system. But when I try to type bengali in terminal the output is messy like this:

[image]

Bengali letters are copy-pasted from Google Bangla Input. The problem is happening only for compound letters. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which method are you using to type Bangla? Is it `gnome-terminal` where you meet the problem? Do you have proper fonts installed, such as the `fonts-beng` package?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I copy-pasted from Google Bangla Input. Previously I used Unijoy keyboard with same results. It's gnome-terminal that I am using. fonts-beng not currently installed on my system.

Comment: So you actually have a problem with rendering of _pasted_ Bangla characters, not with _typing_ them? Then it may indeed be a font issue. Try to install `fonts-beng` to begin with.